# Managing different view modes for a single content type

Tags: 7, entities

I have three different view modes for a single content type on my site. Besides the default and teaser view modes, using Display Suite, I made a custom one called "simplified" . What I need is to make a page view with a list of node titles which would link to the nodes in  the simplified view mode, which would themselves contain a link to the full content view mode.

I am not sure as to what the best way to do this would be. It could be something very simple which I failed to think of, since I am relatively new to Drupal.

I also found the View Mode Page module, which is a great idea, but it doesn't seem to work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it:

1. Set up the default view mode to be a simplified version
2. Enable display suite extras, then "View mode switcher" under "Other"
3. In the detailed and simplified view modes, add the "Switch view mode" field
4. Configure the Switch view mode in each instance to provide links to the other view mode

Your view then should link to your content type with the simplified view and give the user links to toggle the view back and forth between detailed and simplified.

Note that Display suite extras also has a feature called "Switch View Mode", which allows you to set the initial view mode on a node by node basis.

More info in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tiUzobRKKco

Edit: I notice that if you enable "Switch View Mode" in DS extras, there is also the option to use view mode switching by URL, by appending ?v=viewmode to the URL. So, that's another option for linking to a specific view mode from your view. In that case, you'd need to use the Rewrite feature of views to build your own Title links that include the extra view mode parameter.

Comment: Wow, thank you, you were so helpful! I did everything exactly as you said and now I have a perfect switcher from simplified to full view. :)

Comment: No worries. Glad it worked for you!